# R/exams - exams2blackboard no randomization or shuffling

Tags: r-exams

I created a set of **num** and **schoice** questions. I double-checked them with `exams2html()` which gives me the randomization and shuffling of answers I want.

However, when I upload the zip file to the system, I notice that there is no randomization. Code below creates identical 5 questions for both num and schoice questions.

Could you tell what I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Just to follow up: things start working when I created exams with a smaller set of questions. The original had 25 questions.

Comment: I cannot replicate this. Using `set.seed(1)` and `exams2blackboard("deriv.Rmd", n = 2)` I get the those two (distinct) random replications that I also get with `exams2html()`, namely: f'(0.56) = 6.68 and f'(0.78) = 14.60. Hence I would suspect that the problem is rather with your setup/exercises files/directories/etc. Please check and try to provide a minimal self-contained reproducible example.

Comment: When I try 2-3 questions at a time I am able to get the shuffling/randomization, but not when there were 5+ questions. Maybe the problem is with my school's system.  Is it possible to look into zip file to see if randomization worked? Blackboard takes a long time to convert the file.

Comment: This sounds like you have a `set.seed()` in one of your exercises. This will make all subsequent computations seem deterministic.

Comment: did you have a chance to take a closer look at this? It would be great if you could confirm or disconfirm my suspicion. If it is not the seed maybe you could provide a minimal self-contained reproducible example?

Comment: Hello Achim. Sorry, I was in panic mode (the exam is tomorrow) :). It is not about `set.seed()`, I don't set the seed inside the question files. After the exam, I will have more time to experiment. I will try to come up with examples that I can share publically.

Comment: You can also send me the files privately if you want... otherwise waiting for a public example is perfectly fine as well! In any case, good luck tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you! I sent you an e-mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the way that I set knitr options with `knitr::opts_chunk$set()` in a few questions was the problem. Specifically `knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache = TRUE)` was stopping randomization at the exam level.

I removed all `knitr::opts_chunk$set()' from all files, and move the options that I need to the relevant code chunks. All worked beautifuly.

*Thank you so much Achim for finding my mistake!*